# How can I find the SecurityComponent configuration options in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, csrf

I'm starting to get intermittent "blackhole" issues on my CakePHP 3 app. I think that it might be CSRF tokens expiring when a page is left open too long. Old answers (e.g. [this CakePHP 2 one](https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/security-component-auth-blackhole-problem/278)) point to a csrfExpires config key. However, I can't find any reference to any config keys in the [main documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Controller.Component.SecurityComponent.html) or the [code](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Core.InstanceConfigTrait.html#127-187).
Can someone point me to the right documentation, or failing that provide your own info on config keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the security component docs because as of CakePHP 3.0, CSRF tokens are not part of the security component anymore, they are handled by either the (deprecated) [**CSRF component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/csrf.html), or by the [**CSRF middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware).

If it actually is the security component blackholing your request, then it's probably not CSRF related, as invalid CSRF tokens would trigger different errors. Also note that by default CSRF tokens last for the browser session.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the answer, but will leave open for a day or two to give a chance for other responses.

Comment: Out of interest, what else could blackhole a request? Are there lots of possibilities? I am only familiar with the SecurityComponent as a source of blackholes (having checked, I don't have CSRF middleware active).

Comment: @almcnicoll When I'm referring to "blackholes" them I'm also only talking about the security component, as that is where the term stems from. Check your error logs for more information on what exception exactly is being triggered and from where.